# Which file to associate with the Windows boot manager to load GRUB?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-7, live-usb

I installed Ubuntu using a Live USB.

I have a Windows partition and used GParted to create an extended partition in order to lay my new distro.

When I rebooted my computer after the installation, no boot managers were displayed leaving me with no choice but to use my Windows as it's always been.

The only way to use my Linux partition then is to let my USB plugged and tell the BIOS to boot on it (if so, GRUB is displayed on boot).

Then I used BCEdit for Windows to manage the OSes at the start. Now on reboot, I have the choice between Windows 7 or Linux (I managed to create a new entry in the `bootmgr` file).
Anyways, selecting Linux is useless since no file has been related to the entry.

My question is: **What file on my USB drive is responsible to load GRUB when booting from it?**

If I knew what file on my USB drive were responsible of launching the GRUB program, I could upload it on my Windows drive and relate it to the BCEdit program.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from USB again, then running the following command:

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda` (assuming /dev/sda is your hard drive)

This will cause the bootloader to search for all installed OS' and then add them to the list of operating systems present.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to boot ubuntu using windows boot manager(`BCD` perhaps ), you need to install `grub` on the partition where ubuntu is installed. Then you can create entry with `easyBCD` for `grub2`( because ubuntu 9.10 and earlier uses grub2 not grub) and it will be booted up.

now if you are able to boot windows using windows bootloader it means you haven't installed grub(actually grub2) on MBR. Sound confusing ?

[look at my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142750/after-installing-ubuntu-from-usb-grub2-cant-be-installed/142751#142751) and try to install grub on partition where you've installed Ubuntu