# After Installation of Ubuntu 12.04 inside windows No Option To Select Windows or Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, windows

After Installation of Ubuntu 12.04 inside windows No Option To Select Windows or Ubuntu?? i installed Ubuntu 12.04 from usb inside windows and when i restart pc no option to select Windows or Ubuntu ?

Comment: Try re-installing grub http://askubuntu.com/questions/142750/after-installing-ubuntu-from-usb-grub2-cant-be-installed/142751#142751

Answer (score 0):

Which version of windows do you use? Did you use Wubi, since wubi only give Windows bootloader. But if you installed logging from USB, GRUB will be your bootloader. And you should not format the whole disk. That might have got the issue. 
Their might be many reasons for this issue. Recently Windows are coming up with UEFI which blocks other OS and some apps to be installed which aren't licensed. Sometimes Windows 7 got this issue. 
Read the following articles, probably you might come up with where you gone wrong

> Blockquote[UEFI](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/will-windows-8-block-users-from-dual-booting-linux-microsoft-wont-say/10772)

[Way to install or get Dual boot](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/dualboot-windows-linux-oss-computer/)

Best thing to do is Reboot using your usb, and follow this http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.in/2011/06/install-boot-repair-in-ubuntu-1104.html

Comment: i am using win xp sp2 pro

Comment: And one more idea is , boot through USB and try Ubuntu sing USB. Than check is their a partition which is available which mentions the windows partition, which loads in Gpartion when you open to install. That gives you an idea that, you got the windows partition. If it is their, you are lucky and try to clean format the part of linux ext drive which you used to install Ubuntu.. and try reinstalling. That is simple idea

Comment: i installed it in my g  drive /dev/sdb6 and  format ext4

Comment: If Xp than fine. As I said, simple technique is to boot from USB, try to reinstall UBUNTU, that give you partitions which you got at present situation. If you find Windows partitions which mentions NTFS FAT as such, just don't touch it, only format the one which mentions EXT or their flavors, probably that might have got the older ubuntu installed library files, so format only that drive to clean up previous installations, and install Ubuntu on this. This gives you GRub Bootloader, which means you get UBuntu as first option to boot, Ubuntu safe mode and your Windows XP 2. Hope this helps

Comment: yes i done this but not shows bootloder

Comment: Mitch gave a best way to do that