# Operating System loader

Tags: bootloader

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with the option to keep Windows 7.  The installer indicated I could choose the OS to load on startup.  However, only Windows 7 loads when the computer is restarted, with no option for Ubuntu.  What can I do to fix?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148870/after-installation-of-ubuntu-12-04-inside-windows-no-option-to-select-windows-or

Answer (score 0):

What do you see when you start the computer? You should see the BIOS spash screen, then if you had selected grub as the bootloader you would see the grub screen.

If grub is set to silent countdown to starting the default os, you will only see a blank but kinda purplish screen after the BIOS splash. When you see that screen hit Esc and the list of OS should show up. Then you could select the OS you would like to boot into.