# Cannot reach any OS (operating system not found)

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, boot-failure

I know that there are several posts about operating system not found problem. But my situation is severe. My company will start to develop embedded systems on Linux at the end of this year and I wanted to get familiar with Linux.

I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.04. First, Ubuntu did not recognize windows partitions. I try to solve this problem (I do not know and remember what I did here but I think this is the problem). After several hours I manage to install Ubuntu on a 50 GB partition (in fact I think that I successfully install). After rebooting the computer, I see the screen OS not found. I realized that I cannot install Ubuntu properly and cannot boot from Windows 7 now. I use my Windows 7 disk to repair Windows 7 but installation cannot see any harddisk partition and cannot find anything to repair or re-install.

I am in a desperate situation since my work on my work computer is about to get lost. My boss is not happy with that and give me time to solve this problem by the end of this day.

Please Help!!!!!

Ekrem.

Comment: Can you please pop in the Ubuntu Live CD that you might have used to install, and then download and run this script - [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) - and then paste it in a site like [Ubuntu's Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and edit your question to share the link with us?

Comment: I download Boot Info Script but do not know how to use it :(

Comment: Once you've extracted the folder, take a look at the readme file in there, it'll guide you through it :) Here's a [weblink](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/files/bootinfoscript/0.61/) to it.

Comment: look at my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/142750/after-installing-ubuntu-from-usb-grub2-cant-be-installed/142751#142751

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1150180/

Comment: Boot repair starts but never ends and it did not work :(

Comment: By the way when I click on boot-repair or call it from terminal it directly starts updating and then scanning system. I do not see such a console in your post.

Answer (score 1):

From your pastebin, it appears you still have windows.
Give this a try:

Boot into Ubuntu and open the terminal(Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard) or look for it in the dash. Once opened, type the following commands:

```
sudo grub-install "(hd0)"
sudo update-grub
```

This will install grub(the boot manager for Ubuntu on you hard drive.

That should do it.

Tell me if it works. Hope this helps you.

PS. Tell me if you get a picture similar to this:

[image: Example of what sudo update-grub renders]

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo grub-install "(hd0)"
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /boot/grub (is /dev mounted?).
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Comment: How many hard drives do you have on your computer?

Comment: At first I have three, one is for windows and two other seperate partitions. When I was trying to install Ubuntu, I divide another 50 GB part, after that I divide a 10 MB space for bios (ubuntu installation ask me to do) and 4 GB swap area.

Comment: You can maybe use the software that Virpara told you(Specificly in the Grub location tab) As for the console that pops up, that is fine. The software is a GUI for the commands

Comment: but I cannot reach that GUI screen

Comment: yes when I type, a scanning screen comes and scans infinitely, last night I leave the computer in that state hoping that the problem can be fixed after some time but it did not...

Comment: Try typing boot-repair-gtk

Comment: How can I add screen shots here?

Comment: Forum do not let me to upload images due to reputation points :(

Comment: My boot-repair window is much different than the one in the link. I do not have anything under Grub locations and Grub options tabs!

Comment: Any other comments, suggestions??? I can add images after getting 10 reps :(

Comment: Hello, you can download [The Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com). You will need to burn it onto a CD and then boot from it. First get it while I create a new answer will a walk through on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few steps that might help you solve your problem

First, boot into your `Windows 7 repair disk` and click on startup repair. Once the repair is over, you will be able to boot into windows. After you boot into windows, follow the steps in this [link](http://www.microtechnica.org/how-to-remove-ubuntu-12-0-4-dual-booting-with-windows-7/) to remove Ubuntu:

Go to `ubuntu.com` and download the windows installer for Ubuntu and install it.

After installation, you will be able to boot into both the operating systems. Hope it helps