# How to dual boot ubuntu 12.04.2 and windows 8

Tags: installation

I have pre-installed windows 8 in my HP Laptop(64 bit) and I installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 (64 bit) in it. But I cant able to dual boot these two.When I open my laptop it directly opens the windows 8. Please help me

Comment: You have to re-install grub. May have to use USB and access ubuntu live from there.
Check [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142750/after-installing-ubuntu-from-usb-grub2-cant-be-installed/142751#142751)

Answer (score 0):

To boot from a CD you have to press one of the "F" keys immediately after pressing the power button. Unless you can find documentation on it you will just have to mess with it until you find the right button. It should be either "F2", "F8", "F12', or the "Del" button.