# Do I need an active network connection to run boot-repair on the terminal?

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I am sorry as this may be a very elementary question. I'm a brand new ubuntu user and have absolutely no clue what the commands given in the following thread does. I suppose this is what I should be doing as there isn't a boot menu on startup for me to select between windows 7 and ubuntu.

[After installing Ubuntu from USB, GRUB2 can't be installed!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142750/after-installing-ubuntu-from-usb-grub2-cant-be-installed/142751#142751)

My PC doesn't have internet connection at the moment as the LAN port is down and it will take a few weeks for me to get it fixed. When I ran the commands, it failed. Showing an output with something along the lines of:-

Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package boot-repair

Do I require an active internet connection to run the boot-repair commands as in the above linked thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most commands using apt-get will require connectivity.

You could use another computer, and download the [LiveCD](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) version of the tool, which you could use on your computer.